What are the main use case differences of LMS's `releaseMessageContext(messageContext)` & `unsubscribe(subscription)`
Does it mean that using releaseMessageContext(messageContext) on the context messageContext would release the need to manually iterate on all LMS subscriptions?
For example: I could register 10 subscriptions when component is created. Once the component needs to get destroyed we could simply use the releaseMessageContext(messageContext) on the common context of all 10 subscription.
Is that simple?
